# Função em MySQL para retornar texto de acordo com índice numérico

Tags: mysql

Tenho uma tabela chamada `tb_usuarios` com as colunas

```
id_usuario
nome
email
telefone
tipo_de_acesso
```

Gostaria de criar uma função no MySQL, onde ao usar `echo $row['tipo_de_acesso']`, já venha o tipo correto, mas em modo texto, e não numérico, dentre os que eu delimitar:

```
Tipo = 1: Administrador
Tipo = 2: Usuário
Tipo = 3: Cliente
```

Como eu posso criar uma função dentro do MySQL para automatizar isso, ao invés de retornar `1`, `2` ou `3`, retornar então `Administrador`, `Usuário` ou `Cliente`?

Comment: Pode explicar melhor ou editar a pergunta? O trecho `echo $var...` não se aplica a MySql.

Comment: Não terei editáveis, serão apenas 3 níveis (1, 2 e 3)... eu uso o Enum pra me dizer entre 1 e 3, mas gostaria de no mysql conseguir ao invés de retornar 1, retornaria Administrador

Comment: @edilson a ideia é criar um procedure mesmo, dentro do mysql... para fazer isto, bem simples

Comment: Pelo que entendi você está querendo o tipo de acesso em php, certo?

Comment: Exato, mas gostaria de retornar do mysql de forma direta, sem eu precisar fazer if() dentro do PHP ou dentro do SELECT, @Maurivan

Comment: Ok. Sugiro criar uma tabela por exemplo `Perfil` com as características de cada perfil e usar `join` para exibir o perfil do usuário.
Você tem alguma class em php para usuário?

Comment: Não, isso também seria o correto @Maurivan e usar o Join, mas não era isso que eu queria fazer

Comment: Não, isso também seria o correto @Maur

Comment: @AndréBaill sugiro criar uma class para `usuario` já que não deseja utilizar os recursos apresentados pelos colegas. Nesta class deveria ter um método onde exibiria todos os dados de usuário de acordo um `id` ou `username` passado como parâmetro.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Duas soluções com MySQL:

### Função `ELT()`

```
SELECT ELT( tipo, 'administrador', 'usuario', 'cliente');
```

ELT retorna a string da posição indicada pelo primeiro parâmetro, no caso a coluna correspondente ao `tipo`.

As vantagens do `ELT` são o fato de não precisar mexer na estrutura da tabela, e poder decidir seu uso ao elaborar o `SELECT`.

A desvantagem é que se usar a coluna num `SELECT *` (que já não é o mais recomendado em todas as situações) vai retornar numericamente, obrigando seu uso literal em todo `SELECT` que precisar da informação textual.

> Manual: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_elt

### Coluna `ENUM`

Talvez mais simples seja converter a coluna para

```
 ENUM ( 'Administrador', 'Usuário', 'Cliente' )
```

Veja o ENUM funcionando no **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ed6fd5/2)**.

As vantagens são o fato de retornar em texto tanto num `SELECT *` quanto `SELECT tipo`, e ainda assim permitir o retorno numérico com `SELECT 0+tipo`. Seu armazenamento interno é numérico, gastando o mesmo que o menor inteiro necessário para o número de opções. Além disso, funciona com `WHERE tipo = 2` e também com `WHERE tipo = 'Usuário'`, e da mesma forma você pode fazer o `INSERT` com texto ou inteiro, ambos funcionando normalmente.

Além disso, você pode converter uma coluna numérica para `ENUM` sem perder os dados numéricos já existentes, só é importante tomar cuidado de fazer a conversão com os ítens na ordem correta.

A principal desvantagem é o fato de ao acrescentar, remover ou editar qualquer tipo, precisar mexer na estrutura da tabela, e requer um cuidado extra ao reordenar os tipos para não mudar a ordem lógica, de forma a "embaralhar" os dados já inseridos. Além disso, dependendo do quanto você quer respeitar as camadas da aplicação, "embutir" este tipo de informação na estrutura da tabela pode ferir alguns princípios, mas aí é questão de você entender os prós e os contras no seu caso específico.

> Manual: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/enum.html

### Se fosse no PHP

Isto é completamente diferente do que você pediu, mas só vou deixar um exemplo como alternativa para eventuais visitantes. Um equivalente simples em PHP (que tomei como base do seu exemplo na pergunta) seria isto:

Antes de um loop de exibição, algo assim:

```
$tipos_de_acesso=array('', 'administrador', 'usuario', 'cliente');
```

(a coluna `''` é para o índice zero, pois o `'administrador'` é um)

E no *loop*, em vez de `echo $row['tipo_de_acesso'];`, use isto:

```
echo $tipos_de_acesso[$row['tipo_de_acesso']];
```

Obviamente que você deve tomar alguns cuidados para evitar índices maiores que o tamanho do *array*, mas foi apenas para ilustrar um dos caminhos mais simples.

Comment: SELECT ELT( tipo, 'administrador', 'usuario', 'cliente'); este me ajudou, fiz usando desta forma.

Comment: Ok, que bom que resolveu. Mas quando tiver um tempo livre, teste o ENUM pra aprender a usar. Vc vai ver que ele junta as 2 opções com facilidade. Retorna texto, mas pode retornar numérico. O ENUM permite que retorne texto mesmo com `SELECT *`, o `ELT` não. Outra coisa que o enum permite é `INSERT` por texto. Funciona com `INSERT ... SET tipo=1` e `INSERT ... SET tipo='Administrador'` (o elt não ajuda no insert);

Comment: Bacana, muito obrigado @Bacco, me ajudou muito.